# How to use yyparse() of bison somewhere else?

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I have generated the `sintax.tab.hh` and `sitax.tab.cc` with bison successfully and included in `lex.l` to generate the `lex.yy.cc` with the following commands:

```
bison -d sintax.yy
flex lexer.l
```

and I have the 3 corresponding files for a simple parser, in `syntax.yy` and `lexer.l` I don't put any C++ code in the final part; is this right?

I want to use these files in another project that I am working on, so I don't have any idea how to do this.

In my own method declared in another class how can I:

1. specify the input for the parser is going to be a defined string?
2. restart the parser with another string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a lex (flex) question, as the lexer handles the input.

With flex, you can use the functions:

```
yyrestart(FILE * input_file)
yy_scan_string(const char * string)
yy_scan_buffer(const char * buffer, size_t size)
```

to switch the input to some source other than stdin (call these before calling `yyparse`).  There are also a bunch of "buffer" functions you can use to create multiple buffers on the fly and switch between them in the middle of parsing (useful for handling things like 'include' directives).

You can read all about them in [the flex documentation](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html)